# JQuery Datepicker - show day of week name in date cell

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is it possible to show the current day name in the date fields in datepicker?

For example, it would say Monday 25 (instead of 25).

Thanks!

Comment: The advantage of showing just the numeric date is that the cells are very small. Showing the day name (even if possible) would push the cells very wide and adversely affect the layout.

Comment: I've got the datepicker only showing only 7 days in an inline-block. So there's plenty of space above for the day name. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to specify a string on your own. I guess you did not use the api documentation yet.

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

At the bottom of the page you will find the needed information. If there should be any difficulties don't hesitate to comment again.